# How to know the origins of some data loaded in a google map with java?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

is possible to know the location of the file who have the data loaded on this map? http://www.comune.monza.it/portale/mappe/mappa_giardini.html
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lat and Lng of the markers on this map is located within the view source.  Take a look at the Gmarker created from approximately line 741-1126.  Seems like it's all there within the page.

Furthermore, seems like they use jquery, markermanager, pano_layer, and pano map control.

```
<script src="http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/release/src/markermanager.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/system/modules/it.tecnoteca.googlemap/resources/script/pano_layer.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/system/modules/it.tecnoteca.googlemap/resources/script/pano_maptypecontrol.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/system/modules/it.mi.monza.comune.monza_partecipa/resources/script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the datapoints for that are hard coded in the javascript in the html for the mappa_giardini.html file.  Search the file for

```
point = new GLatLng(45.55889209225004,9.266018271446228);
```

Look at a couple of the lines and you'll see how its set up.